# Changing relationships between tables to simplify data access in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Asp.net MVC3 app with Entity framework. Lets say I have 3 tables; Article, Category and Author.

I create relations between 
Category.CategoryId -> Article.CategoryId and Author.AuthorId -> Article.AuthorId
Using code first navigation properties

```
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
```

That means that when I view a list of the articles I have to :

```
return View(db.Article
            .Include(c=>c.Category)
            .Include(a=>a.Author)
            .ToList());
```

In order to have access to the names of categories and authors and not just their id’s

How much would it hurt to break this classic schema and not create relationships between these tables? Then I could just return SelectLists from Author and Category Tables in a ViewModel and populate the Category and Author fields in my Article table directly with the corresponding names not the id’s and also preserve data integrity.
My query would be simplified to just:

```
return View(db.Article.ToList());
```

I suppose I will have to create indexes for those fields to speed up searches.

Is this being done somewhere or is it completely wrong? 
Does it have better or worse performance?

Answer (score 1):

@Panos, your original approach is correct, deleting foreign keys would be a mistake. With the includes you avoid the lazy loading in this scenario and you have a good performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
```

you defined category and Author as virtual and it means these object wont load without an Include command in your query. you man use a select list in your grid without removing these relations, because these relations doesn't have any real load without Include command in your query.

but be aware of using .ToList() this will load all records of your query and later it may become a large amount of data.

Comment: Its the opposite, if you mark field as Virtual you can use lazy loading

Comment: Yes and you can lazy load virtual objects using Include command and without an include command Virtual objects will not load.